# In Koa.js [ObjectObject] while console.log("ctx : "+ ctx.request.body); but if console.log("ctx : ", ctx.request.body); like this it prints JSON

Tags: koa, koa-router

I am trying to console.log("ctx : "+ ctx.request.body);
To view what is in the JSON that received when tried it shows ctx : [object Object].

But if I console.log("ctx : ", ctx.request.body); like this it prints the JSON correctly
without + in console.log().
I want to know what is the reason behind this logic

Answer (score 0):

When you use `someString + someObject`, when the result is a new string. The object must be converted to a string first before the new string can be created.

Whenever an object is cast to a string in Javascript, the result is `[object Object]`.

To see this behavior you can also.

```js
const obj = {};
const str = obj.toString(); // convert to string

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a **formatted** `json` output you also can do the following:

```js
console.log("ctx:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body, null, 2);
```